# The type or namespace name 'Hangfire' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, razor

I'm following the tutorial on Hangfire.io: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html

However when I copy and pasted the provided ~/Views/Emails/NewComment.cshtml code:

```
@model Hangfire.Mailer.Models.NewCommentEmail

To: @Model.To
From: mailer@example.com
Subject: New comment posted

Hello,
There is a new comment from @Model.UserName:

@Model.Comment

<3
```

I ran into the following error:

```
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Hangfire' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   3   The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context
```

Models/NewCommentEmail.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Postal;

namespace HangFire.Mailer.Models
{
    public class NewCommentEmail : Email
    {

        public string To { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It seems when I create almost any other type of Views: in Views/Email: "MVC 5 View Page (Razor), MVC 5 View Page Layout (Razor)...", the page shows all elements preceded with "@" as can't find in current context.
The Project Soln name is "Hangfire.Mailer".

Comment: Can you show your class definition for `Hangfire.Mailer.Models.NewCommentEmail`?

Comment: You can escape the `@` in `From: mailer@example.com` by setting two @: `From: mailer@@example.com`

Comment: Still showing errors for Model and Hangfire.

Comment: @jerryh91 Are those 2 files on the same DLL ?

Comment: How do we know? What dll are you talking about?

Comment: @jerryh91 If the `cs` file and the `cshtml` file reside under different projects in the solution, then you'll need to add a reference in the project that contains the `cshtml` file

Comment: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html#installing-postal

Comment: Probably a bad idea to have Hangfire in the namespace. That's what you're using, but then when you're trying to refer to namespaces it makes it difficult to tell which assembly the namespace is coming from. Usually your models namespace would be something like `MyApplication.Models` where MyApplication is replaced with the name of your application (such as `JerryBlog`).

Answer (score 7):

C# is case sensitive so you should use Hangfire or HangFire.

Now you are using uppercase in the definition:

```
namespace HangFire.Mailer.Models
```

But lowercase in the reference:

```
@model Hangfire.Mailer.Models.NewCommentEmail
```

The page you linked to uses lowercase in the namespace:

```
namespace Hangfire.Mailer.Models
```

Answer (score 1):

*First, (of all, you need to) install the Postal NuGet package* to be able to use this class.

source: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html#installing-postal

Installation package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.Mvc5/

Answer (score 0):

@Ulf's answer seems correct, but you mentioned that also any code preceded with @ is not working also (if I understood correctly).

Do you have a web.config file in your Views folder? you need it to configure razor and other stuff. if its not there, create a new project and copy paste the generated Views/web.config file into your own folder.